# Swap position in singly linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been given an assignment to create various methods for a linked list in C. I am stuck on the swap method which just seems to mess up the entire linked list. Does anybody have any advice on where I am going wrong? Cheers!

Here is my code.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // A list of  pointers to Reminders 
    const int MAX_ENTRIES = 10;
    int numOfEntries = 0 ;
    reminder_t* pFirst = (reminder_t*) malloc ( sizeof(reminder_t));
    reminder_t* pSecond = (reminder_t*) malloc ( sizeof(reminder_t));
    reminder_t* pThird = (reminder_t*) malloc ( sizeof(reminder_t));
    reminder_t* pStart = NULL;
    if (pFirst != NULL)
    {
        strcpy( pFirst->message, "Mikes Birthday");
        pFirst->dateOfEvent.day= 1;
        pFirst->dateOfEvent.month= 1;
        pFirst->dateOfEvent.year= 2013;
        pFirst->pNext = NULL;
    }

    if (pSecond != NULL)
    {   
        strcpy( pSecond->message, "Als Soccer Match");
        pSecond->dateOfEvent.day= 2;
        pSecond->dateOfEvent.month= 2;
        pSecond->dateOfEvent.year= 2013;
        pSecond->pNext = NULL;
    }

    if ( pThird != NULL)
    {
        strcpy( pThird->message, "School Concert");
        pThird->dateOfEvent.day= 3;
    pThird->dateOfEvent.month= 3;
    pThird->dateOfEvent.year= 2013;
    pThird->pNext = NULL;
}

pFirst->pNext = pSecond;
pSecond->pNext = pThird;
pThird->pNext = NULL;
pStart = pFirst;

printf("\n------Before------\n");
listEntries(pStart);
swapPositonOf(pFirst,pThird);

printf("\n------After-aa-----\n");
listEntries(pStart);

getchar();
return 0;
}

void listEntries(reminder_t * pList) 
{
    printf("\n");
    while (pList != NULL)
    {
            printf("%s\n", pList->message);
        pList = pList->pNext;
    }
}

void swapPositonOf(reminder_t* first , reminder_t* second)
{
    reminder_t* pFirst = (reminder_t*) first;
reminder_t* pSecond = (reminder_t*) second;
reminder_t* temp = second->pNext;

pSecond->pNext = pFirst->pNext;
pFirst->pNext = temp;
temp = pSecond;
pSecond = pFirst;
pFirst = temp;
}
```

Expected output:

```
------Before------

Mikes Birthday
Als Soccer Match
School Concert

------After-aa-----
School Concert
Als Soccer Match    
Mikes Birthday
```

Output:

```
------Before------

Mikes Birthday
Als Soccer Match
School Concert

------After-aa-----

Mikes Birthday
```

Comment: Please provide a bit more info: exactly what happens when you sort your list? What is the input, output and expected output?

Comment: Is the code other than the swap function and definition of reminder really necessary?

Comment: Why the redundant casts at the beginning of `swapPositionOf`? (Why the assignment of `first` to `pFirst` & second at all?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to swap the *content* of the list nodes, then it's not hard: you can just do a swap for `message` and `dateOfEvent` fields in the two nodes.

But if you want to swap the *positions* of these nodes (as the name of the function suggests), then you have to pay attention to the `pNext` data member.
In fact, just swapping the node pointers is not enough.
You need to find the positions of the nodes *before* `first` and `last`, and do something like:

```
/* reminder_t* beforeFirst, reminder_t* beforeSecond */
beforeFirst->pNext = second;
beforeSecond->pNext = first;
```

and swap `first->pNext` and `second->pNext`.

Moreover, in these list implementations, in general it's important to pay attention to *special cases* like head node and tail node.

Comment: I have to swap the positions alright, sorry I should of stated that in the question. Will need use this method for sorting later on.

Comment: No problem, it was clear enough reading the name of the swapping function. And swapping pointers is faster than swapping the payload; it does make sense for linked-list node swapping.

Comment: Ok my lecturer gave the empty function:

void swapPositonOf(reminder_t* first , reminder_t* second){}
or possibly
int swapPositonOf(reminder_t* first , reminder_t* second){}

So how can the LinkedList get the previous (it can't be a doubly linked list as far as I know I will ask in class on monday to make sure)

Answer (score 2):

You are not modifying the `pNext` pointer for the nodes just before `first` and `second` nodes.

You need to point the `pNext` of the node preceding "`first` node" to "`second` node" and vice versa.

Suppose the linked list:

`Node_A -> Node_B -> Node_C -> Node_D -> Node_E`

You have to swap Node_B and Node_D:
Total links to break and form:

1. Old Link: `Node_A -> Node_B`....  New Link: `Node_A -> Node_D`
2. Old Link: `Node_B -> Node_C`....  New Link: `Node_D -> Node_C`
3. Old Link: `Node_C -> Node_D`....  New Link: `Node_C -> Node_B`
4. Old Link: `Node_D -> Node_E`....  New Link: `Node_B -> Node_E`

Also remember the corner cases like NULL pointers and consecutive nodes.

Answer (score 2):

You are not swapping it right, what about the node BEFORE the first node and the node BEFORE the second node?

Answer (score 2):

With a singly-linked list, you cannot directly locate the list element previous to the element you want to swap.  You have first, second, and you can directly manipulate them, but you don't have first.prev and second.prev.

You need to traverse your list, and find the nodes which are previous to the two nodes you want to swap (first_previous, second_previous).  Then you node swap needs to also swap the next of each of these previous nodes.

```
reminder_t* first_prev, *second_prev;
first_prev = second_prev = pStart;
reminder_t* iter;
for( iter = pStart; iter; iter=iter->next )
{
    if( iter->next == first ) first_prev = iter;
    if( iter->next == second ) second_prev = iter;
}
```

You will need to fix the above to handle empty list, one element list, and passing first or second at head of list...

Comment: One way to structure a singly-linked list is to have the last element next pointer point to the first element (circular list).  Then you can traverse the whole list given any one element.